# Getting USB device's iInterface from HidD_GetIndexedString in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, usb, hid

I need to get the iInterface of a USB Device, where I've located the device using it's Usage Page and Usage.  We are using the HID classes of the WindowsDDK.  If I know the index to use with HidD_GetIndexedString for iInterface, then I can easily get it.  My problem is that I can't seem to find any way to programmatically figure out what index the iInterface will be at.  Because we are limited to using a subset of the DDK, I can't go the route of using the UsbBuildGetDescriptorRequest.  Is there a way to find this index via what's available in HidD... ?

For the record, I've also tried retrieving iProduct via the HidD_GetProductString - which often contains the iInterface, but it doesn't appear to be consistent - and some of the devices we've tried don't return the iInterface for that.